# $.ajax not working when called from onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code works fine when I call AA.sendRequest() from the console, but not when I call it from an onclick:

```
<a href="/b/Technology" onclick="AA.sendRequest()">Technology</a>
```

For some reason it goes into the error function.

textStatus = "error"
errorThrown = ""

---

Here's a very basic test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/AA.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="login.php" onclick="AA.sendRequest('id');">login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document

var AA;
AA = (function() {
    function AA() {}




    // Request functions
    function sendRequest(){}
    AA.sendRequest = function(id){


        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",

            success: function(data){
                alert("yay");


            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("status:"+textStatus+", "+errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }


    return AA;
})();
```

Comment: Where is the "id" parameter in your call?

Comment: Where is var `AA` defined? Make sure it is in global scope above the html tag.

Comment: The id is an artifact from where I simplified the script to better debug it.

Comment: AA is defined as the function calls

Comment: Works fine for me.  The only issue I have is that `AA` is not defined, so javascript throws an error when you define `AA.sendRequest`.

Comment: @LeeJacobson Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/acdZ4/)** which works perfectly fine.. Now compare this with what you have and find the difference.

Comment: i think you have to provide full path of the link in url... when we calling from a development evironment... this call maybe ok... but from a hosting server it need to be full path to url.... @Diodeus... he's calling ajax 'GET' method, parameter is not an issue...

Comment: @Dasarp Actually, you never want the full path. Without a relative path you have to change it in every environment. Also, the reason the ID is not required is because JavaScript function parameters are similar to variable argument parameters in other languages.

Comment: Are you running this from a "file://" location or "http://"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a context it is difficult to determine what you're trying to accomplish. However, the following should work:

```
var AA = {};
AA.sendRequest = function(id){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajaxPage/b/Technology",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
      alert("yay");
    },
    error: function(error){
      alert(error);
    }
  });
  return false;
};
```

In your HTML:

```
<a href="/b/Technology" onclick="AA.sendRequest('someId')">Technology</a>
```

Comment: I missed the id when simplifying the script. This isn't the problem. Is this actually work for you? What browser are you running?

Comment: @LeeJacobson Are you getting an 'undefined' error? If you get no error after you click the link, then put an alert right before the $.ajax call in your sendRequest function to see if it is being executed at all.

Comment: If I use: error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
The testStatus is "error" with no errorThrown

Comment: @LeeJacobson Then your JavaScript function is working. You need to check the server side log for a stack trace that indicates why it is returning an error, or debug the call.

Comment: Server logging would indicate the request doesn't even reach the server. It errors for some reason before the request has even been sent.

Comment: @Lee Jacobson... please post the (jqXHR.status, jqXHR.statusText)

Comment: @LeeJacobson That is incorrect. The jQuery documentation states the following: "A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror"." That means your request failed on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: try this... var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
 url: newURL + "/ajaxPage/b/Technology"